# How to create a similar background to this one

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Does anyone have a clue how to create a background like [this one](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/#)? Is it possible to do it just with CSS ?

I have chosen ZURB Foundation as my CSS and JS framework so any suggestions including it would be perfect.

Any directions, tutorials and anything would be perfect!

**EDIT**
I am not asking how to use `background-*`, but how to animate it. When viewing it from Chrome the image shows one square and others are starting to circle it.

Comment: Are you really asking how to use [CSS Background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-image)?

Comment: Nope The image is getting generated. Try it with chrome or other browser. It shows one square and starts to show the others one-by-one around it

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: It is not animating for me in Chrome 26

Comment: That's just how the browser renders it when first loading. If you refresh the page after background image is cached it will instantly appear

Comment: @AndrewWalters yeah I checked it again and it appears that it was just the browser...

Comment: I see no animation, you on a really show machine with rendering??

Comment: I rewarded everyone with +1 due to that I have not looked very closely ... Thanks all!

Comment: You can always play with animations to get something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/jpuzT/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
css {

background-image: url(someImage.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: blue;
}
```

The png image has transparency. You can right click on the browser and select "view background image" in firefox to see the image. The image looks like a small image stretched out, causing the pixels to stretch into blocks.

Answer (score 1):

They have this [picture](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/static/showcase/en/a32a0e14e8223a19249778c2853693481ab603ac/stylesheet-resources/images/pixels.png) on background + background color. You can set background with css 'background' property

Answer (score 1):

The background on this website uses [this image](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/static/showcase/en/a32a0e14e8223a19249778c2853693481ab603ac/stylesheet-resources/images/pixels.png); it is not pure CSS. It is essentially the color `#8fc4f8` with a translucent image imposed on top of it and repeated. Here is the full style:

```
div {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #8fc4f8;
    background-image: url(' http://showcase.sproutcore.com/static/showcase/en/a32a0e14e8223a19249778c2853693481ab603ac/stylesheet-resources/images/pixels.png');
}
```